# Using Devise to check a resource against current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Rails 3 and Devise 2.0

In the index view of the Posts resource, I want to display a vote button unless the current_user has already voted.

I am only passing in @posts = Post.all into the index view. What's the best way to check each post to see if the current_user has already voted and render the view accordingly?

I'm currently trying to do this by having a `voted?` method in my Post model, but the current_user method is not available there.

The other solution I see is to have `if letter.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)` in the index view, but I'm not sure if this belongs in view logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `Post`, a `Vote` and a `User` model

And you want to know when a post has a vote from a specific user

One way to do it could be Justin's method, but that will produce way too many database queries than needed

A better solution would be to use a `has_many :through` association like this:

```
class Post
  has_many :votes
  has_many :voted_users, through: :votes, source: :user
end
```

And now you can call `@posts = Post.includes(:voted_users)`

This will eager load all the users that voted on each post

And you could just say

```
if post.voted_users.include? current_user
  #do stuff
end
```

Comment: hmm, never tried this before, but this seems like a better way to do it. Will try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One good solution would be to implement a method in your `Post` model or a helper as follows (assuming post has_many votes):

```
def voted?(user)
  !votes.find_by_user_id(user.id).empty?
end
```

Then, in your view you can put `if post.voted?(current_user)`

You are right, the logic belongs in the model, and the model does not have any knowledge (nor should it) of anything outside the model, such as the current user.  You have to pass it in as an argument

Comment: Ugh, this seems so obvious in retrospect. Thanks Justin.

Comment: Glad to help.  I just made a minor change since, by convention, methods ending in ? should return a boolean.